# In what situation Application_EndRequest is called but Application_BeginRequest is not called?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, page-lifecycle

The expected order of HttpApplication methods is:

1. Application_Start
2. Init
3. Application_BeginRequest
4. Application_AuthenticateRequest
5. (page life cycle)
6. Application_EndRequest

I'm passing through a situation, which throws absolutely no exception, in which, after the Init, it goes directly to ApplicationEndRequest. It doesn't call Application_BeginRequest neither initiates the page life cyle.

What do I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Application_EndRequest` is called but not `Application_BeginRequest` when theres an unhandled exception prior to `Application_BeginRequest`.

That may be on `Application_Start`, the initialization of some module or at `Application_Init`