# mvc3 invokes Application_EndRequest without Application_BeginRequest()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I have a MVC3 App with DevExpress MVC Controls and the default

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

in **RegisterRoutes**, but the following URLs from DevEx includes:

```
/DXR.axd?r=1_3,1_4...
/DXR.axd?r=1_42,1_41,14_18,14_2,...
```

just invoke the **Application_EndRequest()** without an invoke  of **Application_BeginRequest()** before.

At the moment, this leads to strange workarounds for bind/unbind the nHibernate CurrentSessionContext...Probably there are better ways to exclude these URLs as a string compare in **Application_EndRequest()**?

( Ref:

> [In what situation Application_EndRequest is called but Application_BeginRequest is not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541397/in-what-situation-application-endrequest-is-called-but-application-beginrequest)

I could not find any Exeption and it only concerns the above DevEx URLs )

Comment: where are you initializing nhibernate?

Comment: in Application_Start...all other request incl. the "actions" call both Methods and nHibernate works well

Comment: why don't you bind the session handling for nhibernate in session start?

Comment: I have got a similar scenario like **[this](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/11/07/ASPNET-MVC-und-NHibernate-ISession-per-Request.aspx)** to realize the "session per request" pattern

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but I had some strange behaviours with DevEx for other things and I solved all the hassle by removing this line from the web.config from the httphandlers and leaving it only in `system.webServer` -> `handlers`

```
  <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
```

Maybe it will help

Comment: I've commented out the handler, but the behavior has not changed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the special [DX Project Template](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9145) and all required entries are registered.

Check whether or not the issue still persists without the use DX with the standard ASP.NET MVC Project Template.

If this issue related to DX only, I guess it is better to contact their Support Team.

Comment: It could be an approach because I started the project without any DX components and migrated the project later by hand...Are there any failsafe and simple methods to transform my project into a clean template?